# Executing server-side Unix scripts asynchronously

Tags: python, http, unix, asynchronous

We have a collection of Unix scripts (and/or Python modules) that each perform a long running task. I would like to provide a web interface for them that does the following:

- Asks for relevant data to pass into scripts.
- Allows for starting/stopping/killing them.
- Allows for monitoring the progress and/or other information provided by the scripts.
- Possibly some kind of logging (although the scripts already do logging).

I do know how to write a server that does this (e.g. by using Python's built-in HTTP server/JSON), but doing this properly is non-trivial and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Are there any existing solutions that allow for maintaining asynchronous server-side tasks?

Comment: Continuous Integration systems such as BuildBot, Hudson might provide all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Django is great for writing web applications, and the subprocess module (subprocess.Popen en .communicate()) is great for executing shell scripts. You can give it a stdin,stdout and stderr stream for communication if you want.

Comment: Hah! I suspected that Django would be one of the first answers; however, while a nice framework that makes some things easier, I would still have to implement most of the needed interface. I was specifically hoping to avoid having to write all the views for monitoring running tasks.

Comment: Woulnd't that make it more of a question for SuperUser? It sounds like the kind of thing system administrators do.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I recently saw the announcement of [Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html) 1.0, which seems to do much of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SGE](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/), but I think it could be overkill for your need...